# How to calculate probability of complex wave functions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, born-rule

An election has an equation as such: $$Ψ(x) = e^{iαx^2}.$$

How am  I supposed to find the probability of finding the electron over a certain range? Is Fourier Transform involved in this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows a lack of preliminary research.

Comment: To find the probability in a range from $r_1$ to $r_2$, you calculate $\int_{r_1}^{r_2}\psi^* \psi dx$=$\int_{r_1}^{r_2} e^{-i\alpha x^2} e^{i\alpha x^2}dx$=$\int_{r_1}^{r_2} e^{0}dx$=$\int_{r_1}^{r_2} 1dx=r_2-r_1 $

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value of the $\Psi(x)$ describes the probability density. That means, you have to integrate it over the range you are interested in to get the total probability.

If you are not familiar with these concepts, you should probably first understand them :) it is really more interesting to understand something deeply then just to talk about diffuse concepts, even it's quantum mechanics and sounds cool.

No, in this very question fourier transforms are not appropriate.